# magento 2 / can't set addImageToMediaGallery path

Tags: magento2, php, csv

i created php file in root folder and trying to create simple product programatically in magento 2. testimg folder locating in root. I always thow the error: **The image does not exist**. Here is code:

```
$_product->setImage('testimg/test.jpg');
$_product->setSmallImage('testimg/test.jpg');
$_product->setThumbnail('testimg/test.jpg');
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    'testimg/test.jpg',
    null,
    false,
    false
);
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    'testimg/test.jpg',
    null,
    false,
    false
);
```

when i put 'testimg' folder in 'pub/media' and run script:

```
$dir = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    $dir->getPath('media') . '/testimg/test.jpg',
    null,
    false,
    false
);
```

i receive next error:
The file "/home/xxx/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/t/e/test.jpg" doesn't exist or not a file.
Why magento looking for my file in tmp/catalog/product/t/e/ ?

Comment: In my case it was issue if I was saving more than one image in a loop. I save product inside loop rather than saving it after loop and this worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156287)

Answer (score 6):

In Magento 2, the root folder is not by default accessible. You need to put your `testimg` folder in `pub/media` to make it work. Move your folder to `pub/media` and update your code like below.

Here you are using an external php file, so you can do it like below.

```
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$dir = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');

$_product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    $dir->getPath('media').'/testimg/test.jpg',
    null,
    false,
    false
);
$_product->save();
```

Comment: i put the folder in pub/media folder but receive this error:
The file "/home/xxx/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/t/e/test.jpg" doesn't exist or not a file in /home/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:69

Comment: @john, can you share your updated code to question?

Comment: ........updated

Comment: Do you have assigned 777 permission for pub/media folder? File upload functionality works that way, first it copies the file in a tmp folder and then move it to specified location. That's why Magento tries to get file from tmp folder location. Please assign permission and check. @john

Comment: yes i just set 777 perms for pub/media folder and still same error but folders '/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/t/e/' was created but there is no my picture file

Comment: ....any ideas ?

Comment: I am not sure because the same code is working on my setup. Just try to assign 777 permission recursively to **pub/media**

Comment: @John I also get the same error. In my case, I was receiving the error when I was trying to add more than one image for the product.

Answer (score 1):

`'testimg/test.jpg'`should be  put absolute path.

Suppose

If `test.jpg` exit at `/home/XX/public_html/media/testimg` then

You should change:

```
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    'testimg/test.jpg',
    null,
    false,
    false
);
```

**to**

```
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    '/home/XX/public_html/media/testimg/test.jpg',
    null,
    false,
    false
);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, unfortunately that's not helping